# Comparing a 2D array with a number

Tags: python

I have a 2D array of shape say 5000x10, basically like 10 types of values taken 5000 times (thus 5000 profiles), and I want to find see how many of these profiles altogether have a value greater than a number like X. For e.g,

`a=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,6],[-1,2,3,4,-5]])`

Here a has a shape of 3x5, so 3 profiles of 6 types. I want to see how many profiles are completely positive (>0) or fully greater than X, so I have used the following code:

```
d=0
for x in range(3):
        if(a[x,:].all()>0):
            d=d+1
```

But d returns 3, which should not be the case, as `a[2,:]` is not completely positive. 
What can I do in this case?

Comment: Based on `.all()`, this is a NumPy array, right?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you try to use list's `.all()` method, which does not exist, so your code shouldn't work at all:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'all'
```

And if it were a NumPy array, as per [@AKX's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58158980/comparing-a-2d-array-with-a-number#comment102700465_58158980), its [`.all(…)` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.all.html#numpy.ndarray.all) would just test if all elements evaluate to `True`, but negative integers also evaluate to `True` in Python:

```
>>> bool(-1)
True
```

What you should do is use built-in [`all(…)` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 6], [-1, 2, 3, 4, -5]]
d = 0
for inner_list in a:
    if all(x > 0 for x in inner_list):
        d += 1
```

Or you could use [`sum(…)` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
d = sum(1 for inner_list in a if all(x > 0 for x in inner_list))
```

As you can see, I've used `for inner_list in a` in both cases, which is just a nicer way to iterate over list's elements than using its indexes — in your case it would actually be equivalent to:

```
for i in range(len(a)):  # or "in range(3)" in your specific case
    inner_list = a[x]
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,6],[-1,2,3,4,-5]]
d = 0
for x in range(3):
    if (all(e > 0 for e in a[x])):
        d = d+1
```

For `a[x]` equal to `[-1,2,3,4,-5]`, `[e > 0 for e in a[x]]` is equal to `[False, True, True, True, False]`.
Then, `all(e > 0 for e in a[x])` checks if all values in `[False, True, True, True, False]` are `True`.

Comment: There's no need to use list in the argument to `all(…)` — it will actually be a little slower than just using an iterable, since the list will have to be constructed first.

Answer (score 0):

below is the code which might help

```
a=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,6],[-1,2,3,4,-5]])
    d=0
    for iter1 in range (a.shape[0]):
        flag = True
        for iter2 in range (a.shape[1]):
            print (a[iter1][iter2])
            if a[iter1][iter2] < 0:
                flag = False

        print("moving to next row check the flag value="+ str(flag))
        if flag:
            d = d+1
    print("Number of profiles which are positive="+ str(d))
```